Excel Conditional Formatting using Index Match and Wildcards
I have a spreadsheet that reviews payment file names and values that needs formatting to highlight specific lines where the file exceeds a set value based of the file name & its storage location, as there can be some cross over amongst the names and drop locations.
Table 1



File Name
Value
File Storage




TEST_111111_235157
25000.00
folder\Test


TEST_222222_123654
30000.00
folder\Complete



Table 2



Profile Name
User Number
Highest Value
Match Criteria




IND - Test - Claims
111111
20000.00
folder\Test


IND - Test - Refunds
222222
25000.00
folder\Complete



The file name will change daily for every payment sent but they will have core components in each of them that is included in a list alongside its maximum payment value.
I need the conditional formatting to compare the value of the value in Table 1 against Table 2 and highlight if it exceeds that listed highest value, but only if the file name string contains the matching user number and the File Storage in Table 1 matches the Match Criteria in Table 2.
I have tried using an index match to complete this with the below formula but it highlights everything that exceeds the value in the first line of Table 2 instead of making sure they have a matching value for there specific file name.
=$B2>=INDEX('Table 2'!$C:$C,MATCH($C2,'Table 2'!$D:$D,1),MATCH(1,INDEX(COUNTIF($A:$A,"*"&'Table 2'!$D$1&"*"),),0))
This formula is then repeated for B3, B4, B5 etc. depending on how many payments are processed that day to try and cover all eventualities. The date in Table 2 currently has 17 different criteria but this will increase as new payment types are added for new systems.

Is the user number always between the first and second underscore (_) in the filename?

90% of the time it will be between two _ but there could be outliers that break that rule

Not very neat, but works: Values are numbers if they are text then convert them with the VALUE function.
=IF(B2>IF(SUM(IF((IFERROR(SEARCH(rang1,A2),0)>0)*(C2=D$11:D$12),C$11:C$12,0))=0,1E+99,SUM(IF((IFERROR(SEARCH(rang1,A2),0)>0)*(C2=D$11:D$12),C$11:C$12,0))),TRUE,FALSE)

In conditional format, table names cannot be used, has to be replaced with actual ranges or use name manager.
In the example rang1 is defined as Table1[User Number] seen on the screenshot. This can be done with Highest Value and Match Criteria also.

apologies, i should of noted that the data is not in specifically named tables. In the master version of this spreadsheet they are on different tabs, but for the sake of ease on this question (and being new to Stack) i formatted them as that

In formulas you can use both references. Either the "structured reference" of a table in case of User Number column or the excel cell reference as in the other two columns. If the data are on a different sheet the sheet name precede the cell reference like this: Sheet3!D$11:D$12. So than not use Name Manager only replace rang1 with B$11:B$12
